# SocketError in UsuariosController#forgot - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I´m running an app in ruby 1.8.7 with rails 3.2.1 using Phusion Passenger version 3.0.7. I did not develop nor deployed this app and I´m  really new to Rails. This error comes up when the system is sending the user an email with a password recovery link. This probably started after a migration ( I´ve been told ).

Trying to debug the problem I´ve started the app with 'rails server -b 5.39.95.126 -p 8000' in order to see what it would log into the terminal.
To my surprise this way the app works fine. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the configuration of App, the config.action_mailer.smtp_settings was pointing at an inexistent e-mail account. 
Thanks